(Inverse) chirp-Z transform for finer-granularity IDFT
As input, I have the (complex) spectrum of a real signal. By construction, the spectrum has conjugate symmetry. As output, I would like to compute the IDFT of this complex spectrum to obtain the corresponding impulse response.
I am using the Chirp-Z transform (CZT), as I am only interested in a small region of the impulse response (and would like to interpolate the IDFT result in this region). I am using the result that the IDFT can be evaluated as $\text{CZT}(X^{\star})^{\star}$ where $^{\star}$ denotes complex conjugate (since we are only interested in using the CZT on the unit circle).
However, I am getting an unexpected result: any time I do not compute the CZT around the full unit circle, the imaginary part of the output is non-zero. (I would expect the imaginary part to be zero -- the spectrum has conjugate symmetry and so the IDFT would be purely real.)
My understanding of the CZT is that it interpolates the DFT in both magnitude and phase, but apparently some phase shift is being introduced.
Here is a minimal working example (using MATLAB notation, although I have also tried using a Python library and see the same result).
% construct the spectrum of a simple sinusoid (ensure spectrum has conjugate symmetry so IDFT would be real):
test_in = [0,0,exp(1j*pi/4),0,0,0,conj(exp(1j*pi/4)),0];

% compute CZT with default parameters: use 8 evenly-spaced points around the unit circle
test_out_full_unit_circle = conj(czt(conj(test_in)))

% imaginary part of test_out_full_unit_circle is all 0 as expected:
% [1.4142 + 0.0000i  -1.4142 - 0.0000i  -1.4142 - 0.0000i   1.4142 + 0.0000i   1.4142 + 0.0000i  -1.4142 - 0.0000i  -1.4142 - 0.0000i   1.4142 + 0.0000i]

% now compute the CZT for just a subset of the unit circle
test_out_interpolated = conj(czt(conj(test_in),8,exp(1j*pi/32), 1.0))

% imaginary part of test_out_interpolated is now non-zero:
% 1.4142 + 0.0000i   1.0266 - 0.4252i   0.5412 - 0.5412i   0.1493 - 0.3605i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i   0.1493 + 0.3605i   0.5412 + 0.5412i   1.0266 + 0.4252i

I'm completely baffled as to why the output is now complex. My question is: how can I used the CZT to interpolate the IDFT output such that the behaviour would be consistent with zero-padding the IDFT?

It almost appears that a phase modulation is being applied to the output of the chirp-Z transform, but I don't understand why, and therefore I can't correct it.

The spiral defined by your input is $e^{j \pi  m/ 32}$ for $m=0, 1, ..., 6, 7$, which only spans the first quarter of the unit circle, $\phi=[0, \pi/4]$. The input variable test_in is thus considered to be a spectrum with non-zero values at $e^{j \pi / 16}$ and $e^{j 3 \pi /16}$. You need the sample points of the CZT to be conjugate symmetric, $\phi=[-\pi/4, \pi/4]$ at minimum.
